# Using event at google closure template

Tags: google-closure-library, google-closure-templates

I have some problems about google closure template. I'm doing a navigator of websites, which a little kind of complex and with multiple events; now i am using template to create navigator DOM structure but fail to hand events because i don't know if i need to write event using google closure lib but not to use template to auto conduct pure js file.

My question is in this situation, Do I need to handle event separately or can using template to handle event?

Thanks everyone to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

template soy to conduct dom structure and provide function to auto conduct by {namespace}; then in goog lib js file to invoke namespace function and perform event hanlder.
PS: be careful about using soyutils_usegoog.js